# Slide function for icons on touchscreen

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have this slider here, but when I click it, it disappears. I'm looking through it now for hours but it's not possible with my skills to find a solution.

````js
// get our elements
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider-container'),
  slides = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slide'))

// set up our state
let isDragging = false,
  startPos = 0,
  currentTranslate = 0,
  prevTranslate = 0,
  animationID,
  currentIndex = 0

// add our event listeners
slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
  const slideImage = slide.querySelector('img')
  // disable default image drag
  slideImage.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => e.preventDefault())
  // touch events
  slide.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart(index))
  slide.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd)
  slide.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove)
  // mouse events
  slide.addEventListener('mousedown', touchStart(index))
  slide.addEventListener('mouseup', touchEnd)
  slide.addEventListener('mousemove', touchMove)
  slide.addEventListener('mouseleave', touchEnd)
})

// make responsive to viewport changes
window.addEventListener('resize', setPositionByIndex)

// prevent menu popup on long press
window.oncontextmenu = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
  return false
}

function getPositionX(event) {
  return event.type.includes('mouse') ? event.pageX : event.touches[0].clientX
}

// use a HOF so we have index in a closure
function touchStart(index) {
  return function (event) {
    currentIndex = index
    startPos = getPositionX(event)
    isDragging = true
    animationID = requestAnimationFrame(animation)
    slider.classList.add('grabbing')
  }
}

function touchMove(event) {
  if (isDragging) {
    const currentPosition = getPositionX(event)
    currentTranslate = prevTranslate + currentPosition - startPos
  }
}

function touchEnd() {
  cancelAnimationFrame(animationID)
  isDragging = false
  const movedBy = currentTranslate - prevTranslate

  // if moved enough negative then snap to next slide if there is one
  if (movedBy < -100 && currentIndex < slides.length - 1) currentIndex += 1

  // if moved enough positive then snap to previous slide if there is one
  if (movedBy > 100 && currentIndex > 0) currentIndex -= 1

  setPositionByIndex()

  slider.classList.remove('grabbing')
}

function animation() {
  setSliderPosition()
  if (isDragging) requestAnimationFrame(animation)
}

function setPositionByIndex() {
  currentTranslate = currentIndex * -window.innerWidth
  prevTranslate = currentTranslate
  setSliderPosition()
}

function setSliderPosition() {
  slider.style.transform = `translateX(${currentTranslate}px)`
}
var mySwiper2 = new Swiper ('.swiper-container-2', {
  // Optional parameters
  init: true,
  direction: 'horizontal',
  loop: true,
  preloadImages: true,

  /* THIS PAL RIGHT HERE*/ 
  slidesPerView: 'auto'
})
```
````

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper{
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 25px;
}
ul{
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 22px;
}
ul li img{
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  transition: .5s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
ul li img:hover{
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
.slide{
  
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 6px;
  position: center; 
}

.title{
  font-family: Futura;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 0;
}
.grabbing {
cursor: grabbing;
}

.grabbing .slide img{
transform: scale(0.9);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Insta Sory UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="slider-container">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="slide" >
                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0309/8768/1851/files/soy.png?v=1637687581" >
           
                </a>
                <a class="title" >Test</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="slide" >
                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0309/8768/1851/files/soy.png?v=1637687581" alt="">
                </a>
                <a class="title" href="www.eatplants.de">Test</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="slide" >
                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0309/8768/1851/files/soy.png?v=1637687581" alt="">
                </a>
                <a class="title" >Test</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="slide" >
                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0309/8768/1851/files/soy.png?v=1637687581" alt="">
                </a>
                <a class="title" >Test</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors on your browser's dev tools inspect facility console?

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, no im not getting any errors.